# Multi-location update not responding on NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to perform a [multi-location update](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html) in Firebase with the following setting on a NodeJS server:

```
function getPaths(ProductMeta, AuthData, productId) {
  var qPath = Q.defer();
  var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + "/products_tags/");

  console.log("get paths")

  var syncData = {
    timestamp_update: ProductMeta.timestamp_update,
    timestamp_create: ProductMeta.timestamp_create,
    price:            ProductMeta.price,
    nb_sales:         0,    // dynamic (watch out with edit mode)
    rating_avg:       0,    // dynamic (watch out with edit mode)
    rating_count:     0,    // dynamic (watch out with edit mode)
  };

  // Create the data we want to update
  var updatedData = {};

  updatedData["urlslug/" + returnUrlSlug(ProductMeta.title + "-" + ProductMeta.tagline) + "/" + productId] = syncData;
  updatedData["categoryId/" + ProductMeta.categoryId + "/" + productId] = syncData;
  updatedData["productType/" + ProductMeta.productType + "/" + productId] = syncData;
  updatedData["categoryId_productType/" + ProductMeta.categoryId + "-" + ProductMeta.productType + "/" + productId] = syncData;
  updatedData["username/" + AuthData.github.username + "/" + productId] = syncData;
  if(AuthData.github.hasOwnProperty('displayName')) {updatedData["displayName/" + AuthData.github.displayName + "/" + productId] = syncData;}
  var tagsRaw = ProductMeta["tagsString"].split(',');
  for(var i=0; i<tagsRaw.length; i++) {
    updatedData["tag/" + tagsRaw[i].trim() + "/" + productId] = syncData;
  };

  console.log("-----------", updatedData); // works fine

  var onComplete = function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error updating data:", error);
      qPath.reject(error)
    } else {
      console.log("success")
      qPath.resolve("UPDATE_PRODUCTS_TAGS_SUCCESS")
    }
  };
  ref.update(updatedData, onComplete);
  return qPath.promise;
};

function returnUrlSlug(title) {
  return title.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
};
```

I authenticate the user with a custom token which passes the tests fine. My rules look as follows:

```
"products_tags": {
      ".read": true,
      "$method": {
        ".read": true,
        "$tag": {
          ".read": true,
          "$productId": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth !== null 
                      && (root.child('products_meta').child($productId).child('userId').val() === auth.uid
                      || root.child('products_tags').child($method).child($tag).child($productId).val() === null
                      || auth.uid == 'adminId')"
          } // productId
        } // tag
      } // method
    },
```

However, nothing seems to happen when the ref.update() is triggered. There are also no error messages that are being returned, except for a timed out after a while.

What is not working here?

**Update**

I noticed that when you set to `syncData = true`, then the update works. But this seems to me [not consistent with this tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html) where `syncData` (`updatedUser`) is an object.

Comment: Hmm... I don't immediately see what's wrong here. Can you do a few things to help troubleshoot? 1. can you `console.log(updatedData)` and include the JSON in your question, so I can see/try it? 2. can you try to write the same JSON to a location in your database without security rules (just so we know whether it's related to the security rules or not)?

Comment: I just figured out that one of the properties in syncData contained undefined, then basically it does not seem to work.

Comment: That is correct. The client will reject the `update()` call if any of the values is undefined. But you should get an explicit error message about that as soon as you call `update()`.

Comment: Feel free to provide a self-answer. Otherwise I'll vote to close as a typo.

Comment: Weird that I didnt get the error. But I will answer it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that one of my properties in syncData was `undefined`, meaning: the solution works as I explained it.

Frank van Puffelen notes that you should receive an explicit error message as soon as you would try to call update().